# Negating the outcome of scalacheck tests (properties)

Tags: scala, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I am using scalacheck and would like to evaluate the same set of properties on two functions `f1` and `f2`, but I would like to interpret the outcomes differently. For `f1` I would like the properties to pass, while for `f2` I would like the properties to fail.  This is needed for simple mutation testing (to check whether the test is good enough to detect bugs).

I have put my tests in a class, which I parameterize with the function to test. I made the class abstract to prevent the test runner from running this class (otherwise it fails with an error that there is no nullary constructor).

```scala
abstract class MySpec(f: SOMETYPE, suffix: String) 
    extends org.scalacheck.Properties(s"MySpec.${suffix}"): 

    property("trivial") = true
```

Now in a test file I would like to instantiate it twice. Something like this:

```scala
object CorrectSpec extends MySpec(f1, "correct")
abstract class MutantSpec extends MySpec(f2, "mutant")
```

The second spec is abstract to prevent it from executing before I negate the properties.
Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to do this, at least not without a major change to how `MySpec` is written, which I would like to avoid - this is code facing my users, and I would like to hide what I am doing behind the scenes.

I tried various things, but they all end up in one of two corners. I can extract properties using `MySpec(f2, "mutant").properties` and then `map` or `flatMap` to create the negated ones. For example with flatMap (just for the first property, for simplicity):

```scala
mutantSpec.properties(0).flatMap { result => result.status == False }
```

Now that I have the negated properties, I need to add them to some spec objects for execution.

(A) I can inject them in `MutantSpec` (extending `MutantSpec` and using `property.update`). Sadly, I am getting an error that updating properties during execution is not allowed. This is a strange message, as this is not more "during execution" than the other properties defined in the same file. This seems to be caused by the `properties` methods that I use to access the existing "correct" properties. It seems to set a flag that the values have leaked (so further updates are not allowed).

(B) I can also inject the properties into a new spec that does not extend `MutantSpec`. Then the error does not appear (as I am modifing another spec object than the one "frozen" by accessing `properties`. But in order to call `properties` from outside `MutantSpec` I have to instantiate `MutantSpec` which makes `scala-cli` execute the unmodfied `MutantSpec` and by-design this spec will fail (as it is the non-negated spec, running on a buggy `f2`).  This pollutes my test results and breaks CI.

Any idea? Did I get into a corner scalacheck's designers have not anticipated? The second idea (B) seems closer as it runs, just slightly too many tests. Perhaps I can filter **out** the annoying tests with a command line option, but as far as I can see only a positive filter (`-f`) is available. I worked around this by formatting my messages so all the actual tests contain a selected string, and those that are spurious do not. It is not ideal, as it limits the names of tests, but I could not figure out a better way.